# Tomcat deletes uploaded files when undeployment

Tags: java, apache, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

Firstly my topic seems like duplicated, but other solutions didn't help me. I'm also having interesting situation. Antoher computer I have all the same configurations and it works good. But another one it doesn't work good.

I'm uploading file as multipart file via Spring MVC. If I don't undeploy everything works good I saw files in target directory. I also debugged and I can see paths correctly.(Actually when it had been working good a month ago I saw path as src directory, not tomcat's root exploded directory.)

When I undeploy tomcat deletes all uploaded images, so then as you guess I can't see images on my jsp.

That function I wrote

```
 MultipartFile urunResim = urun.getUrunResim();
    String rootDir = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    path = Paths.get(rootDir + "\\WEB-INF\\resources\\urun_resimler\\" + urun.getUrunId() + ".png");
    if (urunResim != null && !urunResim.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            urunResim.transferTo(new File(path.toString()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Urun resmi kaydedilemedi!");
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try copying the files manually to the directory, do the same restart process and see what happened. If the files were deleted then is a tomcat config issue but if the files are still there, then it could be a problem of your application.

Comment: You are writing those files beneath the WEB-INF directory? You should just not do that. It is a deployment folder owned by Tomcat. Reserve a specific place on your hard disk for those files (probably make it configurable for your app),